# Shiny Conditional infoBox Output

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dashboard created with shinyDashboard that will display some operational information. We have 5 areas of our IT organization that we can declare "Touch" or "No Touch", depending on what is going on in the environment.

I am using a simple REST API to get the data, which looks like (single column data frame):

```
Status
eECC:Touch
DOC:Touch
CCC:Touch
GEN:Touch
IT:No Touch
```

That data frame gets written out to an .RData file and loaded using the reactiveFileReader(). Once it's there, I want to build some infoBox()es to display a banner across the top of the screen to show the environments and if they can have changes made in them or not. This is a clip of my ui.R code:

```
 fluidRow(
    h4("Touch / No Touch", align="center"),
    infoBox("ECC", "TOUCH", icon = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon"), width = 2, color = "green"),
    infoBox("DOC", "TOUCH", icon = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon"), width = 2, color = "green"),
    infoBox("CCC", "TOUCH", icon = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon"), width = 2, color = "green"),
    infoBox("GEN","TOUCH", icon = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon"), width = 2, color = "green"),
    infoBox("IT", "NO TOUCH", icon = icon("alert", lib = "glyphicon"), width = 2, color = "red")
    ),
```

So, this is a static example, I know. It was originally put in place as a proof of concept. What I'd like to do is take the input I get from reading the data from the touchNoTouchDF.RData file and have the colors, Icons and text change based upon what's in the RData file.

My first attempt was to use `if else` statements, but it doesn't appear that shiny likes that, or I did it wrong:

```
fluidRow(
h4("Touch / No Touch", align="center"),
if(touchNoTouchDF[1] == "ECC:Touch") {
infoBox("ECC", "TOUCH", icon = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon"), width = 2, color = "green")} else { infoBox("ECC", "TOUCH", icon = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon"), width = 2, color = "green")},
...
...
```

That didn't seem to work, so my next idea was to "build" the string inside the infoBox() function in my dataframe and handle the logic in my R script. Therefore, my data frame (now 2 columns) would look like:

```
Status      UI
ECC:Touch   "ECC", "TOUCH", icon = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon"), width...
```

Then, when building the UI, just simply doing the following:

```
fluidRow(
  h4("Touch / No Touch", align="center"),
  infoBox(touchNoTouchDF[1,2]),
  infoBox(touchNoTouchDF[2,2]),
  infoBox(touchNoTouchDF[3,2]),
  infoBox(touchNoTouchDF[4,2]),
  infoBox(touchNoTouchDF[5,2])
),
```

Well, that just prints the text on the infoBox (in all capital letters, too, seemed strange to me...). Anyway, I can't seem to figure out how to make these infoBox()es dynamic with what I am reading from the RData file. Any tips? Is there a certain function I have to use when calling the text into the infoBox() function other than just the dataframe and row/column? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try rendering infoBox in a server part of a shiny app. Working example below:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(infoBoxOutput('infoBox1'), valueBoxOutput('valueBox1'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$infoBox1 <- renderInfoBox({
    x <- runif(1, 0, 10)
    color <- 'green'
    if(x < 5) color <- 'red'
    infoBox(value = x, title = 'Infobox example', color = color)
  })
  output$valueBox1 <- renderValueBox({
    x <- runif(1, 0, 10)
    color <- 'green'
    if(x < 5) color <- 'red'
    valueBox(value = x, subtitle = 'Valuebox example', color = color)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This worked perfect. I had some other items that did something similar, but being new to Shiny, I'm still trying to pick some things up and understand. Thank you so much!